# Imagekit SDK and NuxtJS: How to import SDK correctly?

Tags: vue.js, imagekit

I am using the Imagekit VueJS SDK and have created a plugin file for it:

`vueimagekit.js` in `/plugins` folder.

```
import ImageKit from "imagekitio-vue"

Vue.use(ImageKit, {
  urlEndpoint: "your_url_endpoint", // Required. Default URL-endpoint is https://ik.imagekit.io/your_imagekit_id
  publicKey: "your_public_api_key", // optional
  authenticationEndpoint: "https://www.your-server.com/auth" // optional
  // transformationPosition: "path" // optional
})
```

I also attached it to the `plugins: [ '~/plugins/vueimagekit.js']` area of `nuxt.config.js`. And my code template is using it like so:

```
    <ik-image
      width="400"
      src="https://ik.imagekit.io/omnsxzubg0/iss061e098033_lrg_x2pIAiRxk.jpg"
    >
    </ik-image>
```

This works fine in my app. However, the docs state that I can also import components individually as needed like so:

```
import { IKImage, IKContext, IKUpload } from "imagekitio-vue"

export default {
  components: {
    IKImage,
    IKContext,
    IKUpload
  }
}
```

Thus, I tried to do this in my `plugins/vueimagekit.js` file but it did not work:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import { IKImage } from 'imagekitio-vue'
Vue.use(IKImage, {
  urlEndpoint: 'https://ik.imagekit.io/omnsxzubg0/'
  // publicKey: "your_public_api_key",
  // authenticationEndpoint: "https://www.your-server.com/auth"
})
```

I get the following error in console:

```
vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:619 [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <ik-image> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.

found in

---> <Pages/photos/index.vue> at pages/photos/index.vue
       <Nuxt>
         <Layouts/default.vue> at layouts/default.vue
           <Root>
```

Anyone got any tips on how I can do this correctly? Thank you!

Comment: I also made sure to transpile the build, but still get same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue. I found that by just changing the import statement in `plugins/vueimagekit.js` to `const {ImageKit} = require('imagekitio-vue')` the "ik-" components work.

Don't forget to add the plugin line in `nuxt.config.js`.

Answer (score 2):

`Imagekit` is a plugin that can be installed and then components `ik-image`, `ik-upload` and `ik-context` can be used globally anywhere in your app, if you want to use `IKImage`, `IKContext` or `IKUpload` individually in your specific file then you don't need to register the `Imagekit` plugin, you can just import the respective component in that file and use `IKImage` component to load image instead of `ik-image` like this -

`<IKImage :publicKey="publicKey" :urlEndpoint="urlEndpoint" :src="your_image_src" />`

or like this

`<IKContext :publicKey="publicKey" :urlEndpoint="urlEndpoint"> <IKImage :path="your_image_path" :transformation="[{ height: 300, width: 400 }]" /> </IKContext>`

Comment: Thx I will try it out and let you know!